# Solving a time dynamic system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following system with a starting point  $x(t_0)$

$$
\dot x =
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{t +1} & 0 \\
1 & \frac{1}{t +1}
\end{pmatrix} 
\cdot x
$$

I wrote the equations as follows:
$$
\dot x_1 = \frac{1}{t +1}x_1 \implies x_1(t) = x_1(t_0)\cdot \frac{t+1}{t_0 +1} \\
\dot x_2 = \frac{x_2(t)}{t+1} + x_1(t)
$$

from there I solved for the case x1 = 0
$$
\dot x_{2_h} = \frac{x_2}{t+1} \implies x_{2_h} = x_2(t_0) \cdot \frac{t+1}{t_0 +1}
$$

Now I got stuck. I looked up the solution and saw that the general solution $ x_{2}$
is calculated as follows:

$$ x_2(t) = \frac{t+1}{t_0+1}x_2(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^t \frac{t+1}{\tau + 1}x_1(\tau)d\tau$$

which means that the particular solution is calculated:

$$ 
x_{2_p} = \int_{t_0}^t \frac{t+1}{\tau + 1}x_1(\tau)d\tau
$$

I don't understand why the particular solution is calculated like that. maybe some steps are missing?
I would appreciate very much an explanation.

thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dot x_2 = \frac{x_2(t)}{t+1} + x_1(t)$ can be rewritten
$$\left(\frac{x_2}{t+1}\right)'(t)=\frac{x_1(t)}{t+1},$$
whence that strange solution:
$$\frac{x_2(t)}{t+1}-\frac{x_2(t_0)}{t_0+1}=\int_{t_0}^t\frac{x_1(\tau)}{\tau+1}d\tau.$$
Note however that:

- since $\frac{x_1(t)}{t+1}=\dot x_1(t),$ this expression can be simplified:
  $$\frac{x_2(t)}{t+1}-\frac{x_2(t_0)}{t_0+1}=x_1(t)-x_1(t_0);$$
- a more usual way to solve for $x_2$ would be to set $x_2(t)=(t+1)C(t),$ and solve for $C:$
  $$\dot x_2 = \frac{x_2(t)}{t+1} + x_1(t)\iff((t+1)C(t))'= \frac{(t+1)C(t)}{t+1} + x_1(t)$$$$\iff (t+1)C'(t)+C(t)=C(t)+ x_1(t)\iff\dots.$$